# Доступ к переменной из другого метода

Tags: java, android

Немного глупый вопрос, но как получить доступ к переменной `web` из метода `onBackPressed`, вынести ее создание за пределы `onCreate` не получается.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        WebView web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web);
        web.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        web.loadUrl("https://site.com");
        web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    }


    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (web.canGoBack()) {
            web.goBack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "ее создание" -- это где вы ее там создаете? Все можно, и даже нужно. В любом туториале по Андроид эти базовые вещи объясняются. Не поленитесь прочесть\посмотреть.

Comment: Определи **WebView web** в самом классе *MainActivity* инициализируй в методе *onCreate* и уже дальше работай с ней в других методах

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Объявите ваш `WebView` как приватное поле класса, и потом сможете его использовать во всех методах этого класса.

```
package com.veboro.prostotech;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    // Объявляем тут
    private WebView web;    

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // инициализируем тут
        web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web);
        web.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        web.loadUrl("https://site.com");
        web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    }


    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

        // Теперь здесь мы можем его использовать
        if (web.canGoBack()) {
            web.goBack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -4):

Что если переопределить `onCreate` чтобы он возвращал `WebView web` как-то так:

```
protected WebView onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState, boolean flag)
```

и потом вызвать его в методе `public void onBackPressed()`

Хотя правильнее было бы все таки вынести `web` как поле класса, и дальше с ней спокойно работать.

Comment: За что меня то заминусили?)

Comment: Минуснули за то, что дан неверный совет. Метод "protected void onCreate()" переопределяется относительно своего базового класса AppCompatActivity. А у переопределенного метода сигнатуру менять нельзя. Да и вообще, onCreate() не предназначен для того, чтобы что-нибудь из него возвращать.

Comment: @MikhailGrebenev в чем проблема создать метод с таким же названием, но другой сигнатурой? И если надо вызывать необходимый метод. Это криво, да. Но в вопросе говорилось что переменную за пределы метода выносить нельзя. Вот и предложен был такой же кривой способ, какой и вопрос.

Comment: Кто сказал что нельзя выносить переменную? Читайте вопрос внимательно, @Slaxor пишет, что у него просто не получалось вынести переменную из метода, но он не писал, что нельзя. В том числе, нельзя рядом с переопределенным методом onCreate() создать перегруженный метод onCreate() с другой сигнатурой. Проверяйте свои советы на практике, чтобы не путать людей.